How to use segfault-handler? Is It Still Usable with Node 20.x
Facing an issue when trying to use the package segfault-handler with Node.js 20.15.0. When working on a Linux VM, I encountered segmentation faults during build and bundle processes with webpack. To debug these issues, I attempted to use segfault-handler to get stack traces but encountered the following error:
bindings@1.5.0-52f1df08c4090fd1c37a/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:135

A similar issue occurs when using the package node-segfault-handler.
Minimal Reproduction
There are no specific reproduction steps available. The segmentation fault started occurring after migrating from Node.js 18 to Node.js 20.
Output
Here is the error log (with some information redacted for privacy):
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/segfault.js:1:23)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14) {
  tries: [
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/build/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/build/Debug/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/build/Release/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/out/Debug/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/Debug/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/out/Release/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/Release/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/build/default/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/compiled/20.15.0/linux/x64/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/addon-build/release/install-root/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/addon-build/debug/install-root/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/addon-build/default/install-root/NodeSegfaultHandler.node',
    '/path/to/node-segfault-handler/lib/binding/node-v115-linux-x64/NodeSegfaultHandler.node'
  ]
}


In general, there's little that an application program can do after a segfault. It often indicates that memory has been corrupted and you can't recover.

Since JavaScript doesn't have explicit pointers, it usually means a bug in the JS engine itself, or libraries that are implemented in languages like C.

The usage of segfault-handler is explained in its README. If you are getting segfaults during a webpack build (maybe caused by a bad plugin), you can try registering the segfault handler in your webpack.config.js.
I gave it a quick try on Ubuntu 24.04 (WSL) with Node.js 20.18.1. I added a file bad-webpack-plugin.js with the following content:
const segfaultHandler = require("segfault-handler");

class BadPlugin {
  apply(compiler) {
    compiler.hooks.emit.tap(
      "Bad Plugin",
      (compilation, callback) => {
        segfaultHandler.causeSegfault();
        callback();
      }
    );
  }
}

module.exports = BadPlugin;

And then imported the plugin into my webpack.config.js and registered the segfault handler like so:
const BadPlugin = require("./bad-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const segfaultHandler = require("segfault-handler");

segfaultHandler.registerHandler("crash.log");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  plugins: [new BadPlugin()],
};

This does give me the expected stacktrace when executing webpack:
$ npx webpack
NodeSegfaultHandlerNative: about to dereference NULL (will cause a SIGSEGV)
PID 5055 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x1
/mnt/c/Users/mwopitz/Repos/node-segfault-handler-test/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x3341)[0x7f83c5675341]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x45320)[0x7f83c7f71320]
/mnt/c/Users/mwopitz/Repos/node-segfault-handler-test/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(_Z22segfault_stack_frame_1v+0x28)[0x7f83c56757e8]
/mnt/c/Users/mwopitz/Repos/node-segfault-handler-test/node_modules/segfault-handler/build/Release/segfault-handler.node(+0x2a57)[0x7f83c5674a57]
webpack(_ZN2v88internal25FunctionCallbackArguments4CallENS0_15CallHandlerInfoE+0x12f)[0xf6e67f]
webpack[0xf6eeed]
webpack(_ZN2v88internal21Builtin_HandleApiCallEiPmPNS0_7IsolateE+0x115)[0xf6f3b5]
webpack[0x1979df6]
Segmentation fault

According to the stacktrace you posted in your question, you are getting compilation errors when installing the segfault-handler. The first step for resolving the compilation errors would be ensuring that all build dependencies are installed. The dependencies are documented in the node-gyp README. For example, on Ubuntu you will likely have to install python3 and build-essential.
